# How can the thickness of gridlines in JSXGraph axis plots be changed?

Tags: javascript, jsxgraph

In the default board axes (eg. https://jsfiddle.net/dr63zumf/1/), screenshot and code below, how can I change the thickness or width of the gridlines to make them thicker? There doesn't seem to be an option for this in the documentation.

Thanks,

Rob

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], axis:true
});
```

[default grid layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmknO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the comment by Rob:

It is not possible to have different widths for `minorTicks` and `majorTicks`, since internally a ticks-element of one axis is one SVG path. However, there are several workarounds possible:

1) Do not show `minorTicks` at all:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], 
    axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
            strokeWidth: 5,
            minorTicks: 0
        }
      },
      y: {
        ticks: {
           strokeWidth: 5,
           minorTicks: 0
        }
      }
    }
});
```

2) If you insist on minor ticks *and* major ticks, then do not show `majorTicks` in the default ticks of the default axes, but add thick ticks without `minorTicks` to the default axes, see https://jsfiddle.net/vf3muqgn/1/:

```
  const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], 
    axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
        x: {
        ticks: {
          majorHeight: 0
        }
      },
        y: {
        ticks: {
          majorHeight: 0
        }
      }
    }
  });

  board.create('ticks', [board.defaultAxes.x], {
    strokeColor: '#cccccc',
    minorTicks: 0,
    majorHeight: -1,
    strokeWidth: 3
  });
  board.create('ticks', [board.defaultAxes.y], {
    strokeColor: '#cccccc',
    minorTicks: 0,
    majorHeight: -1,
    strokeWidth: 3
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be realized with the attribute `defaultAxes`:

```
const board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jxgbox', { 
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5], 
    axis:true,
    defaultAxes: {
        x: {
            ticks: {
                strokeWidth: 5
            }
        },
        y: {
            ticks: {
               strokeWidth: 5
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See it live at https://jsfiddle.net/oucfp3ea/1/

Comment: Thanks Alfred! That's almost perfect, but as well as making the major gridlines thicker (which is what I need), it also makes the smaller ticks in between thicker, which looks odd. Is it possible to just make the major gridlines thicker, and not the little ticks in between?